# Installing mysql-workbench in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-installation, mysql, 19.04, mysql-workbench

The error looks like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-workbench is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'mysql-workbench' has no installation candidate
```

How do I install it?

Comment: Download the .deb file from [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Comment: Hello @SirajusSalekin and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please add the version of Ubuntu to your question and is is always helpful to know, which command generated this error message.

Comment: @SimonSudler wrong person man, but thanks for welcoming me anyway :D

Comment: Oh sorry ;-) auto completion is not always helpful...

Comment: I have added additional resource, tried installing from .deb file, also enabled "Universe" repository, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Melebius mysql-workbench isn't ported to 19.04 as of now (as per apt search and [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql-workbench&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all)). So no effect will take place.

Comment: @Kulfy So, how do I install it?

Comment: @SahilAnsari I'm not sure about that. Workbench from 18.04 or 18.10 can't be installed due to dependency issues. You could wait until they release it for 19.04

Comment: @Kulfy okay, I guess, I have to wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the people not willing to wait, You could try using DBeaver. I can confirm that it works on Ubuntu 19.04. If you insist on Workbench, it is also possible to run the Windows version through wine (performance does not seem to be impacted).

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to install the ubuntu 18 package of mysql-workbench from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

To get this working you first have to fullfill the dependencies:
Download libzip4 from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libzip4 and install it.
The second dependency, which sadly I do not know anymore, you can solve by installing the package via apt.